# WCF net.tcp issued token

Tags: wcf, wif

Does anyone have a current example of using net.tcp with message security mode of issued token. I currently have a security token service that issues tokens but not sure how to configure it with net.tcp. I only see examples of using ws2007FederationHttpBinding

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="wsFed">
      <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" requireSecurityContextCancellation="true">

        <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="IssuedToken">

          <issuedTokenParameters tokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1">
            <issuer address="http://localhost/STSWebHost/STSService.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" />
          </issuedTokenParameters>

        </secureConversationBootstrap>
      </security>


      <tcpTransport />

    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

I keep getting Crypto algorith not supported error? Works fine with ws2007FederationHttpBinding but I am required to use net.tcp. Anyone?

Comment: i did but there is nothing with a custom binding using net.tcp with tokens.

Comment: I have a token service using wsHttpBinding but want to use tokens to the service with net.tcp since I'm behind a firewall. I understand the other bindings but not familar with net.tcp binding but I have a sample working below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a working version by setting allowInsecureTransport=true. I also removed secureconversation since I don't want sessions.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding
     name="netTcpFederated">
      <security
        authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport"
        allowInsecureTransport="true" >

        <issuedTokenParameters keyType="BearerKey" />

      </security>

      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas
          maxStringContentLength="1048576"
          maxArrayLength="2097152" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>

      <tcpTransport
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2162688" />
    </binding>

   </customBinding>`
```